# DB2 IF and LENGTH usage

Tags: if-statement, db2

I have this DB2 table

```
A      |  B      | C

aaaa   |123      |
bbbb   |1        |
cccc   |123456   |
```

All columns are varchars.  I would like to have the column C filled up with the contents of B concatenated with the contents of A.
BUT the max length of C is 8. So if the concatenated string exceeds 8, then i would like to have only 5 characters + "...".

Basically:

```
if(length(A) + length(B) > maximum(C) {
      //display only the first (maximum(C) - 3) characters, then add "..."
} else {
     // display B + A
}
```

How can i do this in DB2?

Comment: What is the context? Is it a SELECT or INSERT statement, a function or stored procedure, or ...? Have you looked at `CASE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good option would be to define column C as generated column so you do not have to handle anything.

```
create table t3 (A varchar(10),
                 B varchar(10), 
                 C varchar(8) generated always as (case when length(concat(A, B)) > 8 then substr(concat(A,B),1,5) || '...' else concat(A, B) end)
                )

insert into t3 (A,B) values ('This', ' is a test');
insert into t3 (A,B) values ('ABCD', 'EFGH');
select * from t3
```

will return

```
A           B           C         
----------------------------------
This         is a test  This ...  
ABCD        EFGH        ABCDEFGH
```

Alternatives could be triggers, procedures, explicit code etc.

Comment: This sounds like an awesome idea. Thank you!